# PostgreSQL best way to model position within scope of foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I have boxes that contain books. The books table has a foreign key called "box_id", referencing the "id" of the box to which it belongs. I need a way to keep track of the relative position of each book within its box. A book can be removed from its box regardless of its position inside the box, but when a book is put into a box, it always goes in last. A book can be moved from one box to another. The order of books inside a box cannot be changed. What's the best way to model this? I prefer not to have a third table.

Comment: Can a book be moved from one box to another? And can the order of the books inside a box be changed? If both answers are "no", then you can simply sort by `id` to get the insert order inside each box.

Comment: Otherwise, you could add a `sort_order` column on the `books` table, with simple numbers from `1` to `n`, so you can re-arrange the order freely.

Comment: A book can be moved from one box to another. The order of books inside a box cannot be changed.

Comment: If you have books "Wind in the Willows", "Ben Hur" and "1984" in box 1 and these are in positions 1,2 and 3 in box 2 and you take Ben Hur out and put it in box 2, do you expect the position of 1984 to change? (e.g. from 3 to 2) or would you expect a gap? i.e. only positions 1 and 3 to change. If the solution can have gaps, then I agree with C14L - just use a sequenced ID. FWIW, I don't think there's anything postgres specific about this question.

Comment: I only care about relative order. Absolute position doesn't matter; i.e. gaps don't matter. Is there a way in PostgreSQL to ensure that an inserted book always goes in last?

Comment: The normalized way would be to create a third table including box_id, book_id and book_position_in_box columns. A denormalized way can be to create a book_id_array column in table `box` because the array types store the order of the items in the arrays. Then you can automatically update this array type column by trigger functions ON INSERT, ON UPDATE, ON DELETE defined on table books.

Comment: @Edouard please post this comment as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Starscream512 - answer added with a full example in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=899542a190421d99e496942f134abb7b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `sort_order` column in the `books` table and use that in an `ORDER BY` clause when you query the books in a box.

You would update the `sort_order` every time you move a book from one box to another (or, put it in a box the first time) with a value larger than the other `sort_order` values in that box - or, for simplicity, with a value larger than all `sort_order` values in the entire table. For that, you can use a sequence or the `current_time()` (assuming you don't move multiple books into the same box in the same transaction). The update can be done either by the client code or using an `ON INSERT/UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Maybe also put a (composite) unique constraint on the box FK and the sort order just to be sure there never can be two books at the same position in a box. And a not null on the sort order.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's the simplest solution that still enforces normalization. I used a timestamp for the "sort_order" column, with a unique composite index on "box_id" and "sort_order". PostgreSQL timestamps are precise to the microsecond (one millionth of a second), so it should be easy to guarantee unique timestamps as long as I don't do bulk updates on "box_id".

Answer (score 0):

The normalized way would be to create a third table including `box_id`, `book_id` and `book_position_in_box` columns.

A denormalized way can be to create a `book_id_array` column in table `box` because the array types keep the order of the items in the arrays.

Then you can automatically update this array type column by trigger functions `ON INSERT`, `ON UPDATE`, `ON DELETE` defined on table `books`, like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION box_insert_update() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  UPDATE box
     SET book_id_array = book_id_array || array[NEW.id] --  book added at the last place in the NEW box
   WHERE id = NEW.box_id ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER box_insert_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON book
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION box_insert_update() ;

CREATE FUNCTION box_update_delete() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  UPDATE box
     SET book_id_array = array_remove(book_id_array,OLD.id) -- book is removed from the OLD box with no gap
   WHERE id = OLD.box_id ;
  RETURN OLD ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER box_update_delete AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON book
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION box_update_delete() ;
```

Full test sample & result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=899542a190421d99e496942f134abb7b).